# What type of attack can bring a website down by serving a redirect loop?

Tags: attacks, iis

My website has been up for a year and all of a sudden is down with a too many redirect message.

www.jdmxchange.com (classifieds for modified cars/parts)

I tried to use fiddler to see if it was redirecting to an external site but it just seems to be redirecting to the same page. I have not pushed any updates to this site so it's strange that it all of a sudden changes. Could this be an attack or some type of glitch on IIS?

- Hosting on windows azure
- Asp.net

It's custom, not some boxed solution so I am able to look at code; however, like I said, I have not pushed any changes to production in a couple of months.

Comment: I'm thinking server config glitch

Comment: Even if changes haven't been made for months?

Comment: Well I'm hoping it's not an attack because that's something I have to deal with. Going to try a fresh deployment to staging and then swap slots to production

Comment: I've seen hosting sites suddenly cause redirect loops due to poorly configured settings on the hosting end. I would contact your hosting support.

Comment: Have you double-checked the spelling of the domain? There's a www.jdm***e***xchange.com that has redirects.

Comment: Yes I'm sure I was going to the right place. It turns out to be some issue with cloudflare that I am trying to get worked out with them.

Comment: I'm also suggesting that your hoster or cloudflare might have a typo in their config that might have caused a redirect loop.

Answer (score -1):

Look [here](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Unvalidated_Redirects_and_Forwards_Cheat_Sheet) at the OWASP article regarding redirects. Check your PHP code.

Comment: Please do not only submit links as an answer because the answer is relevant only as long as the link is alive. Please include the relevant parts of the link in your answer.